# How to display the HOME value through execl function?

Tags: c, environment-variables, exec

For example , `exexl("/bin/echo", "echo", "$PATH", NULL)`. It just show `$PATH`, not the `PATH` value. How can I do it through `exexl` functions?

Comment: `$PATH` is a shell syntax and you are not using any shell here.

Comment: use `getenv` instead... or `system`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It mess me that i can print $PATH under shell command line with "echo $PATH", but not print it by call execl with echo command.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks. I can do that with /bin/sh , but not /bin/echo in execl, is echo not parse the special char like $ ?

Comment: @Samchen echo is not supposed to interpret its arguments, it just prints its args. Common shells interpret command lines by expanding variables, wildcards, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Environement variable are expanded by the shell, not programs like echo

```
exexl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "echo $PATH", NULL);
```

Will call the shell asking it to execute "echo $PATH", and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

since `PATH` is a shell variable, you can't execute like `execl("/bin/echo", "echo", "$PATH", NULL)`. And instead of `execl()` use `execlp()` because it can search for executable in the `PATH` environment variable & can execute scripts.

you want to execute `$PATH`, for that  write one small script like

```
achal@my_system:~$ vi test.sh 
echo $PATH
```

And the run `export PATH=.:$PATH` on command line. And finally execute it using `execlp()` as

```
int main() {
        execlp("test.sh","test.sh",NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Or as suggested by others you can use `getenv()`